# A function to add arguments to a taxonomy

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, taxonomy, advanced-taxonomy-queries

I use a plugin that adds the taxonomy "Vendors" - but not with arguments I need to be able to use a layout designer (Avada-> Layouts) and assign that layout to all "vendors"

I have figured out that if I add the arguments

```
        'show_in_rest' => true,
        'query_var'    => true,
```

to the plugin taxonomy registration it does the trick. But I need some help doing this with a function that doesn't get overwritten at an update of the plugin. (for functions.php)

Original code for registration of taxonomy is:

```php
    public function register_post_taxonomy() {

        $permalinks = get_option('dc_vendors_permalinks');

        $taxonomyname = empty($permalinks['vendor_shop_base']) ? __('Vendor', 'dc-woocommerce-multi-vendor') : $permalinks['vendor_shop_base'];

        $labels = array(

            'name' => apply_filters('wcmp_vendor_taxonomy_name', $taxonomyname),

            'singular_name' => __('Vendor', 'dc-woocommerce-multi-vendor'),

            'menu_name' => __('Vendors', 'dc-woocommerce-multi-vendor'),

            'search_items' => __('Search Vendors', 'dc-woocommerce-multi-vendor'),

            'all_items' => __('All Vendors', 'dc-woocommerce-multi-vendor'),

            'parent_item' => __('Parent Vendor', 'dc-woocommerce-multi-vendor'),

            'parent_item_colon' => __('Parent Vendor:', 'dc-woocommerce-multi-vendor'),

            'view_item' => __('View Vendor', 'dc-woocommerce-multi-vendor'),

            'edit_item' => __('Edit Vendor', 'dc-woocommerce-multi-vendor'),

            'update_item' => __('Update Vendor', 'dc-woocommerce-multi-vendor'),

            'add_new_item' => __('Add New Vendor', 'dc-woocommerce-multi-vendor'),

            'new_item_name' => __('New Vendor Name', 'dc-woocommerce-multi-vendor'),

            'popular_items' => __('Popular Vendors', 'dc-woocommerce-multi-vendor'),

            'separate_items_with_commas' => __('Separate vendors with commas', 'dc-woocommerce-multi-vendor'),

            'add_or_remove_items' => __('Add or remove vendors', 'dc-woocommerce-multi-vendor'),

            'choose_from_most_used' => __('Choose from most used vendors', 'dc-woocommerce-multi-vendor'),

            'not_found' => __('No vendors found', 'dc-woocommerce-multi-vendor'),

        );



        $vendor_slug = apply_filters('wcmp_vendor_slug', $this->taxonomy_slug);



        $args = array(

            'public' => true,

            'hierarchical' => false,

            'rewrite' => array('slug' => $vendor_slug),

            'show_admin_column' => true,

            'show_ui' => true,

            'labels' => $labels

        );

        register_taxonomy($this->taxonomy_name, 'product', $args);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the filter [`register_taxonomy_args`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/register_taxonomy_args/) to manipulate the arguments used for registering the taxonomy just before it is registered:

```php
function wpse_406824_vendor_taxonomy_args( $args, $name ) {
    if ( $name === 'dc_vendor_shop' ) {
        $args['show_in_rest'] = true;
        $args['query_var']    = true;
        $args['show_ui']      = true;
    }

    return $args;
}

add_filter( 'register_taxonomy_args', 'wpse_406824_vendor_taxonomy_args', 10, 2 );
```

You'll need to place this code in a [MU plugin](https://wordpress.org/support/article/must-use-plugins/) or in a custom plugin that's loaded before the marketplace one (I just checked the source of it and they incorrectly register the taxonomy when the plugin loads, instead of on the `init` hook -  the code above needs to already be loaded in order for it take effect).

Comment: The taxonomy name is pulled from permalinks settings (with translations). 
Are these pulled early enough to get the right name of the taxonomy?

```$taxonomyname = empty($permalinks['vendor_shop_base']) ? __('Vendor', 'dc-woocommerce-multi-vendor') : $permalinks['vendor_shop_base'];function wpse_406824_vendor_taxonomy_args( $args, $name ) {
    if ( $name === $taxonomyname) {
        $args['show_in_rest'] = true;
        $args['query_var']    = true;
    }

    return $args;
}

add_filter( 'register_taxonomy_args', 'wpse_406824_vendor_taxonomy_args', 10, 2 );```

Comment: @BeTAiT The taxonomy name is not the label or permalink base. I googl'ed `dc_vendors_permalinks` and found this [source code](https://github.com/wcmarketplace/dc-woocommerce-multi-vendor/blob/master/classes/class-wcmp-taxonomy.php) - if that's the same plugin you're using, the taxonomy name is always `dc_vendor_shop`

Comment: Yes it is. And that is the code and function i've modified: First in file: register_post_taxonomy.

Added your code to a MU plugin but it's not working as hoped so far.

Comment: @BeTAiT I just noticed that `show_ui` is `false` in the source code I linked, but in your question it is `true` - did you change that too? If so you'll need to also set that to `true` in the taxonomy args filter (I've updated my answer).

Comment: Aha! Yes that made the difference. Thanks a lot! Did a pull-request at Git on the changes to.

I changed $name to $taxonomy_name btw.